Romance dialects : sound-to-spelling correspondance?
Romance languages differ greatly in between dialects. What are exemples of Romance languages that have the same writing system, but are written phonetically, with differences between dialects?

It's Romance language dialect. So, Portuguese, Spanish, Italian, French and Roumanian are Romance languages. I don't know about Roumanian (I haven't looked that up) but all those have dialects. So, we say: a dialect of Spanish, for example. Romance languages are all different and have different writing systems.

Dialects usually end up with slightly different writing systems, not the exact same one, and no writing system is truly phonetic.
That is because writing systems are a bit adapted for the sounds of a language or dialect, and also other considerations like uniformity across related dialects, etymology and so on.
(For example, different dialects of English pronounce r differently, but it would be ratha mad to represent that in writing.)
You can find some examples like Galician written with Portuguese orthography, but, again, it is not phonetic.
Writing systems are like maps — not as accurate as satellite photographs, but often more useful.
